Biblical allusion in Slaughterhouse Five?
Kurt Vonnegut, a 20th century American writer who identified himself as a Christ loving atheist wrote this little prayer in a fictional setting, as part of the plot of his "Slaughterhouse five" novel. It could be found on page 52 in the 1969 edition of his book.
"God grant me the serenity to accept the things I cannot change, courage to change the things I can, and wisdom always to tell the difference"
Are there any biblical verses that rhymes with the above excerpt, in terms of what it conveys?

It's known as the Serenity Prayer - Wikipedia:

The Serenity Prayer is an invocation by the petitioner for wisdom to understand the difference between circumstances ("things") that can and cannot be changed, asking courage to take action in the case of the former, and serenity to accept in the case of the latter.
The prayer has achieved very wide distribution, spreading through the YWCA and other groups in the 1930s, and in Alcoholics Anonymous and related organizational materials since at least 1941.
Since at least the early 1960s, commercial enterprises such as Hallmark Cards have used the prayer in its greeting cards and gift items.
The prayer has also made its way into popular culture, including in works by Bill Watterson, Neil Young, Bryan Lee O'Malley and Sinéad O'Connor, and programming including True Detective.
A version of the prayer was originally composed by Protestant theologian Reinhold Niebuhr in the early 1930s. Initially popularized by one of his colleagues, the prayer began to spread widely without reference to the original author.
…
In Kurt Vonnegut's Slaughterhouse-Five, the Serenity Prayer appears in Chapter 3: it is displayed in Billy Pilgrim's optometry office; and though it reassures Pilgrim's patients, the Serenity Prayer underscores the irony of Pilgrim's fatalism.

There was some controversy over its authorship, but Niebuhr appears to be the original author of the concept in this form.
See Serenity Prayer Stirs Up Doubt: Who Wrote It? - The New York Times.
Similar ideas have appeared for thousands of years.
For instance, Epictetus wrote in the 1st century:

Make the best use of what is in your power, and take the rest as it happens.

